# Ansible 1.9.4 : Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation

Tags: ansible

I bumped into `Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation` issue:
https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-apache/issues/50

I posted a lot of details in GitHub.

I googled a lot of "Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation" Ansible complaints, but no simple answer. Any help?

Comment: `Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation` occurs due to permission issues.
since you are using `become`, it should not occur. try `sudo: True` in your playbook. or `become_method = 'sudo'`

Comment: Thanks Frank, yes, I am designating ROOT as connection user in my inventory file, and become: yes should have been enough. Using the old style (sudo:yes) does not help. Trying some of these tips:

Comment: please include the command (yml) and the full error (run ansible or ansible-playbook with `-vvvv`).

Comment: The command and all details are in the github link in the original question. thanks.

Answer (score 48):

I'm also getting this error, while setting up a couple of new boxes. I'm connecting as `root`, so I didn't think it was necessary, but it is:

```
become: yes
```

Now everything works as intended.

Comment: also need to make sure `become_user: root` is in placed

Answer (score 12):

I know this question has been answered a long time ago, but for me, the solution was different. 
The problem was the update_cache step. I had this with every install step, and somehow that caused the "apt failed lock error". 
the solution was adding the update_cache as a seperate step, like so:

```
- tasks:
  - name: update apt list
    apt:
      update_cache: yes
```

Comment: In my case related to ubuntu system or slow cpu. Thank you for the hint! - The update apt list task however fails now when executed separately.

Answer (score 8):

Running the following commands in the same sequence as below should resolve this issue :

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Could you please add _why_ this sequence of commands solves the OP's problem?

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra Due to an old task that did it before.

Comment: This solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 6):

In my case, ansible was trying to  lock `/var/lib/apt/lists/` which did not exist.

The error ansible gave me was `Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation: Failed to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/: E:Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (2: No such file or directory)`

Adding the lists directory fixed the issues:

```yaml
- name: packages | ensure apt list dir exists
  file:
    path: /var/lib/apt/lists/
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the issue in my case on a freshly installed system. After a manual apt update, it worked, but not fully automated.

Comment: this fixed my issue too

Answer (score 4):

The answer from @guaka was entirely correct for me. It lacks only one thing-- where to put `become: yes`.

In the following, there are three places the `become` might go. Only one of them is correct:

```
 - name: setup nginx web server
     #1 become: yes
     include_role:
       name: nginx
       #2 become: yes
     vars:
       ansible_user: "{{ devops_ssh_user }}"
       #3 become: yes
```

In position #2 you will get an unexpected parameter error, because `become` is not a parameter for the `include_role` module.

In position #3 the play will run, but will not execute as sudo.

Only in position #1 does `become: yes` do any good. `become` is a parameter for the task, not for the module. It is not a variable like `ansible_user`. Just to be clear, here's a working configuration:

```
 - name: setup nginx web server
     become: yes
     include_role:
       name: nginx
     vars:
       ansible_user: "{{ devops_ssh_user }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had `remote_user: root` in my playbook, and this happened a lot. I couldn't figure out why, it was happening only on some roles but not others (but always at the same place.) I removed `remote_user: root` and it stopped happening. I just use `--become` and `--become-user=root`. (Which I was using, but it still was randomly failing to get a lock for some reason.)

Answer (score 1):

On my hosts file, I have some hosts that use a different user for `sudo` than the one Ansible uses for SSH so I had `ansible_user` and `ansible_become_user` specified for every host in the inventory.

In those hosts where `ansible_user` == `ansible_become_user` I got `Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation`.

The solution for me was to remove `ansible_become_user` line for those cases where the user is the same in both parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the silly problem was that I had the same host in my inventory, but under two different DNS names.

So, apt was legitimately locked in my case, because I had multiple ansible connections to the same host doing the same thing at the same time. Hah! Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there is nothing wrong with Ansible, SSH or the role. It is just that apt in Debian can get really confused and lock itself out. As I was using a home-brewed Docker VM, I only had to recreate my image and container to get APT working again.

Comment: I totally fail to understand why this was downvoted. In my case it was a similar issue ( see e.g. [1](https://github.com/boxcutter/ubuntu/issues/73) or [2](https://github.com/QubesOS/qubes-issues/issues/2621)  ), and one would obviously have to investigate the `apt` locks in order to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error while using ansible to set up a ceph cluster. Just running the ansible-playbook without *sudo* did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

adding `become: yes` to the **task** is solved my problem.

```
- name: Install dependencies
  apt:
    name: "{{ packages }}"
    state: present
    update_cache: yes
  vars:
    packages:
    - package1
    - package2
    - package3
  become: yes
```

Answer (score -1):

https://serverfault.com/questions/716260/ansible-sudo-error-while-building-on-atlas

> Check `ps aux | grep apt` output for suspicious processes.

Comment: That is a comment but not an answer to the problem